# Jquery mobile selectors for controls in embedded pages

Tags: jquery, mobile, css-selectors

I have multiple data-role pages in an html page and I'm having a hard time accessing div tags to set text, html, etc from `$('#myPage').live` events/methods.  I've tried `$('#myPage #myControl')` as well as just `$('#myControl')` and neither work.  Any ideas?

Comment: do you want to add html/text to `#myControl`?

Comment: I don't know what that means, hint?  Oh wait, I got it.. thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('body').on('click', '#myPage', function() {
  // do you code
  $(this).text('Clicked');
  // if you want to add text/html to #myControl then try
  $('#myControl', this).text('Clicked');
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to set a selected option in a select menu with data that I'm loading from local storage.

Comment: I'm marking your question as the answer because it showed me how to access controls in embedded pages.  The "this" seems to be the key to it.  Thank you for the help and the reminder to look back over the answers to my other questions.